# How to color a single logical page among the eight printed on a physical page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

is it possible to color a single logical page among the eight printed on a physical page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=23pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in,bottom=0.3in,footskip=2em,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pocketmod}

\title{A PocketMod Booklet}
\author{R. Noureddine}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, almost the same solution too

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the `pocketmod` package, but this colors a single page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=23pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in,bottom=0.3in,footskip=2em,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{pocketmod}

\title{A PocketMod Booklet}
\author{R. Noureddine}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-3]
\newpagecolor{yellow}
\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
\lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Feel free to like/accept. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can "colour" a page using the `absolute positioning` of `tikz` if you add the following code to the page in question. Depending on the position within your text, it may overlay or stay behind your text. You will need the `positioning` library from `tikz`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[red,opacity=0.2] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The [`wallpaper`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/) package allows setting a background (image) for the current page, using code such as `\ThisCenterWallPaper`.

Either one should reference your logical page; Depending on how you group the pages together on your physical page, you may have to adapt your code.